# Mobile First Platform Appcenter access from Mobile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I Create the IBM Appcenter Installer for Iphone and deployed into the Appcenter and I access the appcenter console from the Mobile.

http://Honstname:9080/appcenterconsole/installers.html  I am able to see the new installer(IBM App Center), When I click the install I am getting the error called.

cannot install application because the certificate is not valid.

I download the IOS enterprise development certificate from the developer.apple.com, I don't know where I can install this certificate in server or?, if mobile means how can I gave this certificate to every customer.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you must setup the server with SSL support.

There are too many steps to detail here, so it is based for you to review the full set of instructions in the following user documentation topic: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_ac_ssl_config.html%23configuringsecuresocketslayerssl